# Kindly guide me what is missing

Tags: java, jsp

I am creating my first java web application..
Actually the problem I am facing is in **ManageAllStudents**. It should show the list of information of students after retrieving it from the database.

I'm using the below code but it doesn't show the information or doesn't retrieve the information from the database.

Kindly guide me what I am missing. This is my code:

```
 <% try {
          Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
          String url =  "jdbc:odbc:stdProjectDataDSN";
          Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
          String sql = "Select * from students ORDER BY ID DESC";
          PreparedStatement pStmt = c.prepareStatement(sql);  
          ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery(sql);

          while (rs.next()) {
 %>
           <tr height="40">   
               <th> <%=rs.getString("ID")%> </th>
               <th> <%=rs.getString("Name")%> </th>
               <th> <%=rs.getString("RollNumber")%> </th>
               <th> <%=rs.getString("PhoneNumber")%> </th>
               <th> <%=rs.getString("StudyProgram")%> </th>
               <th> <%=rs.getString("Status")%> </th>
               <th> <a href="ManageAllStudent.jsp">update</a> </th>
               <th> <a href="ManageAllStudent.jsp">delete</a> </th> 
           </tr>
 <%
         }
         rs.close();
         pStmt.close();
         c.close();
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
     }
 %>
```

Comment: Please properly format your code so we can read it.

Comment: Also if you have any error from console please post it,

Comment: I believe this is JSP, correct?  If so, it should be tagged as such.

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr i hope now its better to look

Comment: @iNan no error only doesnot show the information form db

Comment: @HotLicks yup..thank you let me do it

Comment: Am I wrong or is there no `<table>...</table>` in the output?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov There is table other rows too but i only place that part where code is..

This is basically the try part

Comment: Hello try this `pStmt.executeQuery();` no need of sql parameter

Comment: it shows me no error show me just perfect html page but doesn't show the **db values**

Comment: @iNan no good luck:( the above you mention not works

Comment: You have an empty catch-clause. You should add a print statement in the catch-clause in case of any error occurs.

Comment: ok let me tell you where i place the db file..

Comment: @FredrikLS there is a catch clause & it shows the error when i place any wrong code

`catch (Exception e) {
                        }`

Comment: @iNan i am developing this in Netbeans and the data base file is in the below mention directories

**\src\java**
**\build\web\WEB-INF\classes**

Comment: @mobi001 i need to know your error.

Comment: @hawaii.five-0 sir it shows me no error it display a perfect html page..but doesn't show the data from db

Comment: @mobi001 view source of your generated html, can u figure out anything??

Comment: How can the catch clause show any error when you don't print it out? Have you tried adding e.printStackTrace(); to your catch-clause and looked in the console?

Comment: add e.printStackTrace and tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got what iam missing i didnot configure my database in control panel->administrative tools...

So when i set it up it just work:)

thank to all specially @hawaii.five-0 who gave me a wonderful & helpful sugesstions

Answer (score 1):

```
PreparedStatement pStmt = c.prepareStatement(sql);  
ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
```

There is no reason to call `executeQuery(sql)` you already use `PreparedStatement`.
Probably problem is here. So try it change.

Second, you have to call `close()` method in `finally` block because if it will crash, `catch` block will called but your `close()` methods no.

`Finally` block guarantees that will be called always.

**Update:**
You need to avoid writing raw java code in JSP file. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Comment: **HTTP Status 500**


type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 104 in the jsp file: /build/web/ManageAllStudent.jsp
rs cannot be resolved
101:            String Name; 
102:            String PhoneNumber;  
103: 
104:                                         while (rs.next()) {
105:                                 %>
106: 
107:                         <tr height="40">

Comment: its too long i cant post the all the basic is above mentioned

Comment: so you writing raw java code in JSP, you need to avoid this, see my answer, there is a link.

Comment: it means i have to write the class individually?

Comment: yes you should have clear java classes and call only methods. so fot example you should create this like method that returns List.